# EOFError python

Tags: python

[image: лог]

В pycharm код работает без ошибок, но когда его проверяет сторонний компилятор возникает ошибка. Он ругается на последнюю строчку

```
x = int(input())
y = int(input())
k = 0
b = 0
s = 'север'
u = 'юг'
z = 'запад'
v = 'восток'
r = 'разворот'
vp = 'вперёд'
direct = s
x1 = 0
y1 = 0
if x == 0 and y == 0:
    print('0')
    print("север")
a = input()
while a != 'стоп':
    if x == x1 and y == y1:
       j = k
       h = direct
       x1 = 0
       y1 = 0
       print(j)
       print(h)
    else:
    if a == r:
        if direct == s:
            direct = u
        elif direct == v:
            direct = z
        elif direct == u:
            direct = s
        elif direct == z:
            direct = v
        a = input()
        k += 1
    elif a == vp:
        a = ' '
        b = int(input())
        k += 1
        if direct == s:
            y1 += b
        elif direct == z:
            x1 -= b
        elif direct == u:
            y1 -= b
        elif direct == v:
            x1 += b
    elif a == 'направо':
        if direct == s:
            direct = v
        elif direct == v:
            direct = u
        elif direct == u:
            direct = z
        elif direct == z:
            direct = s
        k += 1
        a = input()
    elif a == 'налево':
        if direct == s:
            direct = z
        elif direct == v:
            direct = s
        elif direct == u:
            direct = v
        elif direct == z:
            direct = u
        a = input()
        k += 1
    else:
        a = input() #та самая строчка
```

Comment: По-моему сторонний "компилятор" (на самом деле интерпретатор) тупит ;)

Comment: Добавьте текст задания в вопрос. Тут во вводе нет никакого "стоп", возможно как раз нужно отлавливать это исключение и завершать цикл. И еще `a = input()` не нет смысла делать в каждой ветке `if` - сделайте его один раз после `if`. Ну и отступы у вас в коде в вопросе неправильные. Если проблема не в отступах - поправьте код в вопросе так, чтобы он выглядел именно так, как он выгладит у вас - с учетом всех отступов.

Answer (score 0):

зачастую после последней строки ожидается пустая строка

вообще проверьте свой код изначально на PEP8 стандарт (можно тут - http://pep8online.com/) и исправьте найденные ошибки

Comment: Ошибок нет, дело не в PEP8

Comment: а 27 строчка с неправильным отступом нормально проходит или это только на данном сайте так получилось?  `else: if a == r:`

Comment: Неправильные отступы получились только в тексте проблемы, итоговый код выглядит правильно, pep8 ошибок нет. Единственная ошибка описана в скриншоте.